# How to control who add me in their circles in Google+?

Tags: google-plus

I am annoyed everyday. Unknown people are adding me to their circles. How to allow only the people in my 'Extended Circles' to add me to their circles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't stop people from adding you. 
If you don't post public you have nothing to worry about, they will never see a thing. If you post public even people who have not added you to their circle will see the post if they visit your profile. Even people who have not joined Google+ will see it. Public really means anyone.
So either way you have nothing to worry about people adding you to their circles. It makes no difference at all.

Comment: If you want to further ensure you don't hear from them, you can "Block" them.

Answer (score -2):

just go to the option of HAVE YOU IN CIRCLES and just select action button in wright side and in action click select all and again press action button click  block.Everyone will be blocked even some oof your frns might be blocked then click action buttton and in that click view blocked then you'll get blocked list if it contains your frns u can unblock them and add them in your circles.

Comment: Why would you want to block everyone? That seems counter-productive.

Comment: You would want to block people totally because millions of people were forced into signing up with Google plus JUST to be able to leave comments on youtube videos, and millions of people are DARN ticked off about it too. Most of them didn't join youtube as another ridiculous facebook account, but Google has forced everyone to do just that.  Even though the above question was before that change, it still fits. Even if you join because of the social networking aspects of it, you should still have full control over who adds you and who doesn't.

Comment: That the person blocked can or cannot see your posts is not the issue. The problem is that if someone does a search on the blocked person, you may come up as a contact as part of their circle. If you wish to disassociate yourself completely from this person you cannot unless they delete you.